# Replace widgets like fragments in Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm new to Flutter.

I have an app with 2 sub widgets (2 fragments in Android), and when i clicked next button in WidgetA, I want to replace (or push) that widget into WidgetChildA, like push (or replace) fragments in Android. But instead of that, I got a fullscreen widget like a normal screen in Flutter.

**Here is my code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DemoFragment extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new DemoFragmentState();
  }
}

class DemoFragmentState extends State<DemoFragment> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(context.toString() + context.hashCode.toString());
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Demo fragment")),
      body: new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          new FragmentA(),
          new FragmentB()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FragmentA extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(context.toString() + context.hashCode.toString());
    return new Center(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text("Fragment A"),
          new RaisedButton(
              child: new Text("next"),
              onPressed: () {
                print(context.toString() + context.hashCode.toString());
                Navigator.of(context).push(new PageRouteBuilder(
                    opaque: true,
                    transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 0),
                    pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) {
                      return new FragmentChildA();
                    }));

                /*showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
                          title: new Text("Hello world"),
                          content: new Text("this is my content"),
                        ));*/
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FragmentB extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(context.toString() + context.hashCode.toString());
    return new Center(
        child: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Text("Fragment B"),
        new RaisedButton(
            child: new Text("next"),
            onPressed: () {
              print(context.toString() + context.hashCode.toString());
              Navigator.of(context).push(new PageRouteBuilder(
                  opaque: true,
                  transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 0),
                  pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) {
                    return new FragmentChildB();
                  }));
            })
      ],
    ));
  }
}

class FragmentChildA extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: new Center(
            child: new Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[new Text("Fragment Child A")],
    )));
  }
}

class FragmentChildB extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: new Center(
            child: new Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[new Text("Fragment Child B")],
    )));
  }
}
```

Screenshots:

[Home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNR8P.png)
[image]

[After clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFEtm.png)
[image]

Comment: Where you want to replace? You want to replace the button with your fragment?

Comment: I want to replace FragmentA to FragmentChildA

Comment: im looking to do this too, ive got a few ideas, i dont really want the entire thing to be stateful and swap the widget on a conditional, i wonder how the bottom navigation view does it, do you have any update on this

Comment: @ChâuMinhPhúc could you resolve your problem?

Comment: @ChâuMinhPhúc Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I found out the way to handle this case for a few months, but I just forgot to answer this question.

The solution is wrapping your Widget with a new Navigator.

You can see the video example [here](https://streamable.com/1h2mw)

And the simple demo for it [here](https://github.com/phucgaoxam/demo_navigator_flutter)

The downside of this solution is sometimes, the keyboard is not showing as my intention.

Comment: id like to recommend putting the code solution here on SO. Rather than linking to an external resource only.

Comment: Video link is broken ):

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if you can use the router to replace just the part of a view; but you could conditionally change which Widget you render in the build method, like this:

```
children: <Widget>[
    someCondition ? new FragmentA() : new FragmentChildA(),
    new FragmentB()
],
```

Then you just need to set `someCondition` by using `setState` in the stateful widget:

```
setState(() => someCondition = true);
```

If you want to do this from inside `FragmentA` you could allow it to have the function passed into its constructor:

```
new FragmentA(
  onPress: setState(() => someCondition = true)
)
```

However, it might be better to encapsulate all of this logic inside a single widget so this logic isn't all hanging around in the parent. You could make a single `StatefulWidget` for FragementA which keeps track of which stage you're on, and then in its build method renders the correct child widget, something like:

```
build() {
  switch(stage) {
    Stages.Stage1:
      return new Stage1(
        onNext: () => setState(() => stage = Stages.Stage2);
      );
    Stages.Stage2:
      return new Stage1(
        onPrevious: () => setState(() => stage = Stages.Stage1);
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah, I understood this state concept of Flutter, but I wonder if there is a way similar to Android.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android dev, so not sure how it works there, but I don't think you can just replace a part of a widget in Flutter, because when the parent build method is called, it's just going to create the old widget again.

Comment: @Danny Tuppeny could you help me on this topic?  `https://stackoverflow.com/q/56223550/1830228`

Answer (score 5):

You could simply use a MaterialApp widget with the CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder as pageTransitionTheme like

```
MaterialApp(
   theme: ThemeData(
   pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(builders: {
   TargetPlatform.iOS: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
   TargetPlatform.android: SlideRightPageTransitionsBuilder(),
   }),
   initialRoute: "fragment1",
   routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      "fragment1": (BuildContext context) => Fragment1(),
      "fragment2": (BuildContext context) => Fragment2(),
   }
...
),
```

Then in fragment 1 you simply use the following to navigate to the other fragment with a slide animation

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("fragment2");
```

Answer (score 2):

ok I'm going to be doing this the same way google does it with the bottom navigation bar, I don't see this as the most performant but it works

```
  class MainFabContainer extends StatefulWidget {

    MainFabContainer({
      Key key,
    }) : super(key: key);

    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
      return MainFabContainerState();
    }

  }

  class MainFabContainerState extends State<MainFabContainer> {
    String title = "Title";
    int _currentIndex = 0;
    final List<int> _backstack = [0];

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      //each fragment is just a widget which we pass the navigate function
      List<Widget> _fragments =[Fragment1(navigate: navigateTo),Fragment2(navigate: navigateTo,),Fragment3(navigate: navigateTo,)];
      //will pop scope catches the back button presses
      return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () {
          customPop(context);
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          drawer: drawer(),
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(title),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: _fragments[_currentIndex],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }


    void navigateTo(int index) {
      _backstack.add(index);
      setState(() {
        _currentIndex = index;
      });
    }

    void navigateBack(int index) {
      setState(() {
        _currentIndex = index;
      });
    }

    customPop(BuildContext context) {
      if (_backstack.length - 1  > 0) {
        navigateBack(_backstack[_backstack.length - 1]);
      } else {
        _backstack.removeAt(_backstack.length - 1);
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    }
    //this method could be called by the navigate and navigate back methods
    _setTitle(String appBarTitle) {
      setState(() {
        title = appBarTitle;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: whats `navigateTo` in fragment parameters and when i press back button i get `Unhandled Exception: Scaffold.geometryOf() must only be accessed during the paint phase.` error

Comment: its in my answer, and your error sounds like your trying to change the wrong widget

Comment: could you say whats `navigateTo` parameters in fragment parameters? and how about using them

Comment: its in the answer i think you need to scroll the answer it shows 2 methods navigateTo and navigateBack void navigateTo(int index) {
      _backstack.add(index);
      setState(() {
        _currentIndex = index;
      });
    }

    void navigateBack(int index) {
      setState(() {
        _currentIndex = index;
      });
    }

Comment: yes i know that, please let me to create new issue and link you that, thanks