# Flutter Page View how to not always start at the initialPage?

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface

It may sound complicated but I try to explain what Im trying to do

I have a Page View that contains different pages and also another page view like this:

```
PageView(
  controller: pageController,
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  children: [FirstPage(), 
             SecondPage(), 
             SmallPageView(), 
             ThirdPage()])
```

While this works as intended there is one problem: The `SmallPageView()` has 4 Pages. When I went through its pages and I am at `ThirdPage()` and press the Back Button, which calls:

```
pageController.previousPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400), curve: Curves.ease);
```

I am in  `SmallPageView()` at page 1 again. Which makes sense since it is the `initialPage`and the `previousPage` of the `pageController`. However when I am at `ThirdPage()` and press the back button I would like to go to the **last** page of the `SmallPageView()` which is obviously more intuitive

I tried doing things like

```
pageController.previousPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400), curve: Curves.ease);
smallPageViewControllerHouse.jumpToPage(4);
```

Which doesnt work and I suppose would look ugly.

I also cant assign a variable to initialPage of the controller to change it dynamically. Is there a way to 'remember' where a page view was instead of starting at the initial page everytime time?

And of course you could argue to just resolve the `SmallPageView()` and put its 4 pages into the `PageView()` instead of a nested page view. But this is a design solution and to achieve the look I am going for there is no other way (as far as I know atm) than doing it with a nested page view

Comment: In android you have to manage fragments using fragment manager. Check this thread, this will solve your problem:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56223550/flutter-switch-between-fragments-by-supporting-back-to-previous-fragment

Answer (score 0):

try to use IndexedStack, pageview inside indexedstack will maintain it's state

```
IndexedStack(
  index: _currentIndex,
  children: [FirstPage(), 
             SecondPage(), 
             SmallPageView(), 
             ThirdPage()])
```